# Insert a map into other map with a unique type key

Tags: c++11

hello guys i am new to maps in C++ i am having a question regarding copying a particular type map to another map of same kind the details are shown below
I initially declared a map like this

```
map<string,int> objmap,obj_porcess ;
 for(int i = 0; i < 10]; i++) {
 obj_process[to_string(i)]=i+10//some processing the to_string is just in case but i have strings with names for all 10 values
 }
```

like

```
obj_process["today"]=1;
obj_process["yesterday"]=-1;
obj_process["tommorow"]=2;
```

now i want to define some thing like this just my key word should be added with the process and remaining all can be same for all the keys from obj_process

```
objmap["process_"+"today"] = obj_process["today"];
```

instead of defining all 10 can i have a simple code cause in here i took an example of 10 but i have like 200 set of different strings in the key of map

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you iterate over the map?

`for(auto &i : obj_process)
        objmap["process" + i.first] = i.second;`

Comment: this won't work, u're not concatenating strings, u're adding pointer and number

Comment: i'm pretty sure it's `std::string("process") + i.first`  or `"process" + to_string(i.first)`

Comment: I'm pretty sure you should ask to a compiler instead before any comment. A new `std::string` is implicitly built from a `const char *`. `to_string(i.first)` means nothing to me.

Comment: aww my bad, i was constantly thinking that i.first is integer, sorry

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you need:

```
map<string,int> objmap;
map<string,int> obj_porcess;

//
// Fill up the contents of obj_porcess
//

// Copy objects from obj_porcess to objmap using a computed key.    
for ( auto& item : obj_process )
{
    objmap[std::string("process_") + item.first] = item.second;
}
```

Comment: just to inform "process+" if u are using " (the quotation marks) it tells the type as string any ways thanks for  the idea

Comment: @SakethPothukuchi, yes, I realize that. I prefer to use explicit types as a coding style. It's easier for me follow such code.