# Insert a map into other map with a unique type key (2)

Tags: c++11

hello guys i am new to maps in C++ i am having a question regarding copying a particular type map to another map of same kind the details are shown below
I initially declared a map like this

```
map<string,int> objmap,obj_porcess ;
 for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
 objmap ["process"+to_string(i)]=i+10//some processing the to_string is just in case but i have strings with names for all 10 values
 }
```

like

```
objmap["process_today"]=1;
objmap["process_yesterday"]=-1;
objmap["process_tommorow"]=2;
```

now i want to define some thing like this just my key word should be added with the process and remaining all can be same for all the keys from obj_process

```
obj_process["today"]=objmap["process_today"] ;
```

instead of defining all 10 can i have a simple code cause in here i took an example of 10 but i have like 200 set of different strings in the key of map
i already asked a qn for exact opposite one [this was my previous qn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44744341/insert-a-map-into-other-map-with-a-unique-type-key) now when i try its vice versa i got an issue hope i find some help

Answer (score 0):

If you can initialize both at the same time, the solution is straightforward:

```
const std::vector<std::string> days = {"today", "yesterday", /*...*/};
for(const auto& d : days)
{
    objmap["process_" + d] = foo();
    obj_process[d] = foo();
}
```

---

If you cannot, you should be able to iterate over `objmap` and get rid of the `"process_"` prefix with some basic string manipulation:

```
constexpr auto prefix_length = 8; // length of "process_"

for (const auto& p : objmap)
{
    const auto& key = p.first;
    const auto& processed_key = key.substr(prefix_length);

    obj_process[processed_key] = objmap[key];
}
```